# GET Request works with python 'requests' library, but does not work with curl

Tags: php, python, curl

I need to probably modify my cURL request to make it work.  You can find the needed url from searching on [Qantas](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/home/ca/en)  for example (Melbourne to Sydney, one way, the next day flights), you get a page with the results. Then if you mouseover the flight number, you get a dialogue box. In FF network, you can see a get request happen as you mouseover which retrieves a json document.

The cURL code that does not work:

```
$flight_data_url = 'http://book.qantas.com.au/pl/QFOnline/wds/FlifoInfoServlet;jsessionid=eFVNx9ORnACoaRyRp_Iu675LrmM6JfRkDHpa2c6I60bhJABPBeW3!764143094!1637886517!1440118985617?AIRLINE_CODE=QF&B_DATE=201508220600&B_LOCATION=MEL&E_LOCATION=SYD&FLIGHT_NUMBER=400&LANGUAGE=GB&SITE=QFQFQFBD'

$handle = curl_init();
$options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_CAINFO => $path . '\cacert.pem',
                CURLOPT_URL => $flight_data_url,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Host'=>'book.qantas.com.au','User-Agent'=>'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)','Accept'=>'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01','Accept-Language'=>'en-US,en;q=0.5','Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip, deflate','Content-Type'=>'text/javascript; charset=utf-8','X-Requested-With'=>'XMLHttpRequest','Referer'=>'http://book.qantas.com.au/pl/QFOnline/wds/OverrideServlet','Cookie'=>$flight_cookie_file,'Connection'=>'keep-alive')
            );

            curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);
            $flight_model_data = curl_exec($handle);

            curl_close($handle);
```

The python code that does work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests


def getaurl():

    url = 'http://book.qantas.com.au/pl/QFOnline/wds/FlifoInfoServlet;jsessionid=LuJYL8OJHk_DUIPcYbcfT343gYMEw3b9ej4Vt_MATLerQG0kNIZR!932397328!976639289!1440293569417?AIRLINE_CODE=QF&B_DATE=201508240630&B_LOCATION=MEL&E_LOCATION=SYD&FLIGHT_NUMBER=404&LANGUAGE=GB&SITE=QFQFQFBD'

    headers = { "Host":"book.qantas.com.au",'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0', "Accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.5", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Content-Type":"text/javascript; charset=utf-8", "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest", "Referer":"http://book.qantas.com.au/pl/QFOnline/wds/OverrideServlet", "Connection":"keep-alive" }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    print r.text

getaurl()
```

Comment: You are saying it is not working but without replicating the code locally and using your certificates maybe we cannot debug your code. Can you check if you get a curl error ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: There is no curl error, it is returning a page with a 404 not found error rfc 2068.  Whatever that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i debugged your code. You are doing two things wrong to get it to work.

1 ) you need to tell curl that it needs to handle a GZIP encoded connection

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
```

2 )  set your headers using  as per manual (it is not a key => value list) search CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

A full working example. Just change the url and the cookie value to make sure the session is working

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Fixed by Bizmate.biz</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$flight_data_url = "http://book.qantas.com.au/pl/QFOnline/wds/FlifoInfoServlet;jsessionid=Wzpc3MHW1Z1dQVnKNgjL1zGOFYs5jTi0yey2JJB3OsumjMe42a8C!-111476454!1015406667!1440372015574?AIRLINE_CODE=QF&B_DATE=201508261625&B_LOCATION=YVR&E_LOCATION=LAX&FLIGHT_NUMBER=3352&LANGUAGE=GB&SITE=QFQFQFBW";

//$flight_data_url = 'http://book.qantas.com.au/pl/QFOnline/wds/FlifoInfoServlet;jsessionid=eFVNx9ORnACoaRyRp_Iu675LrmM6JfRkDHpa2c6I60bhJABPBeW3!764143094!1637886517!1440118985617?AIRLINE_CODE=QF&B_DATE=201508220600&B_LOCATION=MEL&E_LOCATION=SYD&FLIGHT_NUMBER=400&LANGUAGE=GB&SITE=QFQFQFBD';

$handle = curl_init();

$flight_cookie_file = 'DWM_XSITECODE=QFQFQFBW; wt_21=false; QSession=D884F2710404EC6F60E402761C3296A8; TLTUID=8B4FCC6D7E9CD0AC141750417B7DDB37; qantas_isDevice=type#desktop|os#Linux; _wt.user-676736=WT3vpi-xU8uREVQbLyHDUf1TwZLPluq_yfjSdWFE4rxld2gVwcxlwtwsrUqhlQL-MMM-zC-j0Nk1MDugbvMEcuRZWkUrevpXCBQnAHuAQ~~; amdfa=done; pastSearchCookie=REGION:am:TRIPTYPE:O:FROM:Vancouver:TO:Sydney:DEPDAY:Wednesday:DEPMONTH:8:DEPYEAR:2015:RETDAY:Wednesday:RETMONTH:10:RETYEAR:2015:FLEXIBLE:false:ADULTS:1:CHILDREN:0:INFANTS:0:TRAVELCLASS:ECO|REGION:am:TRIPTYPE:O:FROM:Vancouver:TO:Sydney:DEPDAY:Wednesday:DEPMONTH:8:DEPYEAR:2015:RETDAY:Wednesday:RETMONTH:10:RETYEAR:2015:FLEXIBLE:true:ADULTS:1:CHILDREN:0:INFANTS:0:TRAVELCLASS:ECO|REGION:am:TRIPTYPE:R:FROM:Vancouver:TO:Sydney:DEPDAY:Monday:DEPMONTH:9:DEPYEAR:2015:RETDAY:Wednesday:RETMONTH:10:RETYEAR:2015:FLEXIBLE:false:ADULTS:1:CHILDREN:0:INFANTS:0:TRAVELCLASS:ECO|; aam_uuid=09862152334998442092616937494749808238; s_cc=true; s_fid=77B7E8432AD3E6A0-170B4CF864D887BC; s_qntttc=1440372017198; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_vi=[CS]v1|2AED21DE051D0C8B-40001905C00064CC[CE]; aam_uuid=09862152334998442092616937494749808238; _wt.mode-676736=WT3PVZU041xU6Y~; webserver=server44; 3_uc=region#AM|tvldate#20150826|arr#SYD|locale#en|dep#YVR|country#ca';

$headerArray = array(
    'Host: book.qantas.com.au',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,it-IT;q=0.4,it;q=0.2',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer: http://book.qantas.com.au/pl/QFOnline/wds/OverrideServlet',
    'Cookie: ' . $flight_cookie_file,
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Pragma: no-cache'
);

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
    CURLOPT_URL => $flight_data_url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headerArray

);

#
curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);

$flight_model_data = curl_exec($handle);



if(curl_exec($handle) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($handle);
}
else
{
    echo 'Char encoding ' . mb_detect_encoding($flight_model_data) . ' <br/><br/>';

    echo 'Operation Completed without any errors : <br/>' . $flight_model_data . " ENDED\n\n <br/><br/>";

    file_put_contents("test.txt",$flight_model_data);

    echo "<br/>header : " . json_encode(curl_getinfo ($handle) );
}

curl_close($handle);
?>
</body>
</html>
```